# What am I doing wrong on my update function on nodejs/mongodb?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I am currently new to nodejs and mongodb what I want to do is make a function to update my win,lose,draw record from my userschema.

My Schema:

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:'string',
    password:'string',
    email:'string',
    //Change Made
    win:{ type: Number, default: 0 },
    lose:{ type: Number, default: 0 },
    draw:{ type: Number, default: 0 }
});

var db = mongoose.createConnection(app.get('MONGODB_CONN')),
    User = db.model('users', UserSchema);
```

My Function for updating:

```
app.post('/user/updateScores',function(req, res){
try{
      var query = req.body.username;
      User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { win : req.body.win, lose : req.body.lose, draw : req.body.draw }, function (err,user){
           if (err) res.json(err) ;
             req.session.loggedIn = true;
             res.redirect('/user/' + user.username);
      });
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
  });
```

The problem is when I try updating, it updates the current data BUT goes to a blank page and throws an exception saying:

```
ReferenceError: win is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\ryan-utb\Desktop\RockScissorsPaper\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:1176:16), <anonymous>:5:9)
    at template (C:\Users\ryan-utb\Desktop\RockScissorsPaper\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:1184:21)
    at Function.exports.underscore.render (C:\Users\ryan-utb\Desktop\RockScissorsPaper\node_modules\consolidate\lib\consolidate.js:410:14)
    at C:\Users\ryan-utb\Desktop\RockScissorsPaper\node_modules\consolidate\lib\consolidate.js:106:23
    at C:\Users\ryan-utb\Desktop\RockScissorsPaper\node_modules\consolidate\lib\consolidate.js:90:5
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

but I already defined win properly, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
User.update(
    {username:req.body.username},
    { win : req.body.win, lose : req.body.lose, draw : req.body.draw },
    function (err, data) { //look - no argument name "user" - just "data"
    //2 mistakes here that you should learn to never do
    //1. Don't ignore the `err` argument
    //2. Don't assume the query returns something. Check that data is not null.
    console.log(data);
    //The next line must be INSIDE this function in order to access "data"
    res.redirect('/user/' + data.username);
});     
//ACK don't try to access "data" (or "user") here. this is asynchronous code!
//this code executes EARLIER IN TIME than the User.update callback code
```

**update after your snippet v2**

- your `find` call is simply not matching any documents, so `user` is null
- FYI You can do a find and update at the same time with a single `findOneAndUpdate` operation

Comment: Hi Peter! I have updated my code to do all of the comments you have placed. Check it out and I have a new error that has come out

Comment: Is it okay to ask how to that? "You can do a find and update at the same time with a single findOneAndUpdate operation" I am very lost at the moment

Comment: The stackoverflow guidelines encourage "thoroughly researched" questions. Read the mongoose documentation. For me to just fix your code is not going to be long-term beneficial compared to you taking a minute to learn the basic mongoose API.

Comment: Hi and I did what you told me to do and researched about findOneandUpdate and thank God it works, I updated version 3 of my code snippet and I have a new problem saying that win is not defined? but I already defined win properly. Why is that? @Peter Lyons

Comment: Now the error is in the template for the next page you load. Different problem entirely.

Comment: I think your query is still not correct. But as @PeterLyons said, reference error doesn't seem to be in the code you have posted. You can add print statements at different stages of your code and check which code is executed and which is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
  User.update({
    username: req.body.username
  },{
    $set: {
        win : req.body.name,
        loose : req.body.loose
    }
  }, function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
   } else if (result === 0) {
      console.log("user is not updated");
   } else {
      console.log("user is updated");
   }
 });
```

I hope you can understand your issue and can update your User collection.